# How to config ignore single line statement in eslint/tslint?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint, typescript-eslint

I wanna never using non-block statement.

Like,

```
if (pass)
  continue; // (X)
```

```
if (pass) {
  continue; // (O)
}
```

Is there options for eslint/tslint?

Comment: do you mean `// eslint-disable-line`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using eslint, then the rule is called [curly](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/curly). From reading your question, it was not clear whether you want to disable or enable this rule. To get you started, though, in your [`.eslintrc.json`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started#configuration) configuration file, you can disable the rule like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "curly": "off"
    }
}
```

You can read about the other options for `curly` here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/curly#options

Answer (score 0):

Related.
I was trying for the opposite of this post request.

Look at `nonblock-statement-body-position`

For example:

```
'nonblock-statement-body-position': [
      'error', //
      'beside',
      { overrides: { while: 'below', for: 'below', if: 'below' } },
    ],
```

It's not well documented, for example, `for`, `if`, etc can also be given too.

See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/nonblock-statement-body-position